# Best method to parse an HTML document and replace whole segments of tags

Tags: java, html, vb.net, parsing, replace

I am trying to find the best way to parse an HTML document from top to bottom and 
replace certain groups of tags for something different and create an updated file. 
I prefer to use Java, VB.NET or PHP.

There are several classes, such as JSoup, Jericho etc. which seems to be good to replace specific tags, but what I am trying to do is to replace/rewrite a whole segment.

For example I might be looking for a table, such as.

```
<table><tr><th>A header</th></tr><tr><td>Some text</td></tr><tr><td>More text</td></tr></table>
```

and I want to replace this with

```
<div class="header">A header</div><p>Some text. More text</p>
```

However, want to leave the rest of the HTML document the same.

Anyone done this? What is the simplest approach? Can you recommend a good HTML parser to use?

The document I am parsing is XHTML, so I have considered using java DOM or SAX tools, however, I found these quite cumbersome and was wondering if there was a better way to do it, with some existing classes.

Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need an html parser to parse an html easily and properly. You can use

[jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org)

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM.

It is as simple as this to parse an html using soup:

```
String html = "<table><tr><th>A header</th></tr><tr><td>Some text</td></tr><tr><td>More text</td></tr></table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: Yes, I had a look at Jsoup, but as I mentioned, it seems geared towards changing specific tags, but I found no examples of replacing a segment of tags. Take a table for example, you may not know how many rows it contains. Or maybe there just wasn't any good examples? How would you use Jsoup to accomplish the result in my example?